# Response code:Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Getting this exception while executing the load test in Jmeter, I am using `JMeter 5.4.1` and `Java version 1.8`.

```
"Response code:Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: protocol_version"
```

. It will be a great help if you can figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates mismatch between [SSL protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) used by the application you're testing and JMeter.

Check which protocol(s) does your server support using [OpenSSL tool](https://www.openssl.org/) like:

```
openssl s_client -connect your-host:your-port
```

this way you see which SSL protocol is being used by your server, once you figure this out - you will be able to amend `https.protocols` Java system property or `https.default.protocol` / `https.socket.protocols` JMeter properties to match what does your server expect.

More information:

- [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks a lot for guidance it was really helpful. I have checked with the server supported protocol and set it in the jmeter.properties file.